# Angular Select box returning Object

Tags: angularjs, select, html-select

I have an Angular select dropdown that is populated from a constant.
When updating the model the select doesn't update and:
I am using track by ID but for some reason when an option is selected the whole object is returned instead of just the ID.

Could someone please have a look at this plunkr and let me know where I went wrong. https://plnkr.co/edit/UJMeR0gregFaavhT5wxs?p=preview

```
<select id="property_type_id" class="form-control"
    ng-model="proptype_id"
    ng-options="ptypes.Description for ptypes in proptypes track by ptypes.ID"
    >
<option value="">Please select Type</option>
                                                    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
<select id="property_type_id" class="form-control"  
              ng-model="proptype_id"
              ng-options="ptypes.ID as ptypes.Description for ptypes in proptypes track by ptypes.ID">
     <option value="">Please select Type</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I want the model = ptypes.ID with your change the model now takes the Description, also assigning the value 2 to the model doesn't change the select drop-down to the correct value

Comment: Ok thanks, ptypes.ID as ptypes.Description works, updates the model to the correct value, but why doesn't the $http call update the dropdown to the correct val?

Comment: Please help me with the second part of my question, I don't want to open a new one: Why doesn't the drop-down update after the model is updated?

Comment: what display in console in http call? this  console.log(re.data);

Comment: Ok removing the "track by" solved my issue, thanks. According to this question I had to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36718995/angular-select-not-updating-after-model-updates